# Razor Exception after upgrade ASP.NET from RC1 to core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I had a running ASP.NET 5 RC1 application. Now I have converted the application with the help of Shawn Wildermuth's blog to the current ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 version. The api controllers do run without any problem. But as soon as I try to open a *.cshtml file I get the following errors:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Error: Connection id
>   "0HKTRFIA80GPS": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException:
>   One or more compilation failures occurred:
>
> rkq2e32e.x02(16,11): error
>   CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

...

> rkq2e32e.x02(37,10): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> rkq2e32e.x02(37,10): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Does someone has an idea where I can start from?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the exception by comparing the project.json with a new project.json from an up and running ASP.NET Core version. Actually I didn't find the cause - I just discovered that the exception is gone after adding preserveCompilationContext - true entry to my project.json:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
 }
```